# nested dictionary from dict1 and dict2 using keys from dict1 and values from dict2(which are keys in dict1)

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

```
users = {'196': ('110', '1'), '186': ('269', '1'), '22': ('68', '4'), '196': ('650', '3')}
movies = {'110': 'Operation Dumbo Drop (1995)', '186': 'Blues Brothers, The (1980)',  '269': 'Full Monty, The (1997)', '68': 'Crow, The (1994)', '650': 'Seventh Seal, The (Sjunde inseglet, Det) (1957)'}
```

My code to create a nested dictionary with keys a unique list of users (keys from users) but using keys from movies to replace values of movies IDs (first item of value list from users) and keeping scores (second item of value list from users) is:

> users_preference = {k: list(set().union((*map(lambda x: [x for x in movies.values()], v[0])) ))  for k, v in users.items() }

But this returns all movies for each user, and I don't know how to add scores to this. Could you please help? Thank you.

The expected output is similar to:

```
users_preference = {'196': {'Operation Dumbo Drop (1995)': '1', 'Seventh Seal, The (Sjunde inseglet, Det) (1957)': '3'}
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you posted your expected output instead of just describing it in words.

Comment: Why do these users have a 2-tuple with `'1'`?

Comment: Sorry yes the expected output:
`Dct3 = {'196': {'Operation Dumbo Drop (1995)': '1', 'Seventh Seal, The (Sjunde inseglet, Det) (1957)': '3'}

Comment: @LMHull edit the expected output into your question, please. Don't post it as a comment.

Comment: There is a duplicated key on the users dictionary '196'.

Comment: @DanielMesejo good catch

Comment: @LMHull the keys in dictionaries must be uniques I suggest you change the user structure, to a dictionary where the values are list of tuples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected output cannot be achieved using the format of `users`, I suggest you change to a dictionary where the values are a list of tuples:

```
users = {'196': [('110', '1'), ('650', '3')], '186': [('269', '1')], '22': [('68', '4')]}
movies = {'110': 'Operation Dumbo Drop (1995)', '186': 'Blues Brothers, The (1980)', '269': 'Full Monty, The (1997)',
          '68': 'Crow, The (1994)', '650': 'Seventh Seal, The (Sjunde inseglet, Det) (1957)'}

user_preference = {user: {movies.get(movie, movie): rank for movie, rank in preferences} for user, preferences in
                   users.items()}

print(user_preference)
```

**Output**

```
{'196': {'Operation Dumbo Drop (1995)': '1', 'Seventh Seal, The (Sjunde inseglet, Det) (1957)': '3'}, '22': {'Crow, The (1994)': '4'}, '186': {'Full Monty, The (1997)': '1'}}
```

Comment: You are actually so right about this. I have got the wrong dictionary `users`! I am iterating through a data file to get `users` and so far I have picked up just one movie per user, instead of list of tuples as you very correctly suggested. Thanks for your attention to detail.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dct3 = {k:(movies[v[0]],v[1]) for k, v in users.items()}
```

Keep it simple, you can use keys to access values from movies dict.
Just think of it as creating a new tuple as values for each key in users.

Comment: Thank you very much, really appreciate it. I feel so much better know after so many hours of trying this.

Comment: No worries at all, welcome to the world of programming :) @LMHull

Answer (score 1):

More verbose

```
Dct3 = {}
for k, v in users.items():
  v = list(v)
  v[0] = movies[v[0]]
  Dct3[k] = v

print (Dct3)
#=> {'196': ['Seventh Seal, The (Sjunde inseglet, Det) (1957)', '3'], '186': ['Full Monty, The (1997)', '1'], '22': ['Crow, The (1994)', '4']}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can issue

```
{user:(movies[movie_id], score) for user, (movie_id, score) in users.items()}
```

which produces

```
{'186': ('Full Monty, The (1997)', '1'),
 '196': ('Seventh Seal, The (Sjunde inseglet, Det) (1957)', '3'),
 '22': ('Crow, The (1994)', '4')}
```

Note that there is a duplicate key in your dictionary `users` (`'196'`). (Pointed out by Daniel Mesejo in the comments.) Dictionary keys must be unique, so `users` actually looks like this:

```
>>> users
>>> {'186': ('269', '1'), '196': ('650', '3'), '22': ('68', '4')}
```

**~edit~**

Traditional `for` loop that does the same.

```
result = {}
for user, (movie_id, score) in users.items():
    result[user] = (movies[movie_id], score)
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much. I am learning python so I didn't know that keys must be unique. Very happy now, embarrassingly I tried to do this for about 5 hours...

Comment: @LMHull If you are new to Python, my tip is to stick to traditional `for` loops before writing oneliners. Once you figured out how the different data structures operate, you can venture into list-, dict- and set-comprehensions.